# Error: System.FormatException when converting Georgian date to Hijri Date

Tags: c#, datetime, date-conversion, hijri

I am getting following error when converting Georgian date to Hijri Date:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

My code as below:

```
string dateString;
string format = "M/dd/yyyy";
DateTime result;
CultureInfo arSA = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
arSA.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

DateTime dt = 1/6/2018 12:00:00 AM;

result = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString());

dateString = result.ToShortDateString(); //dateString => "1/6/2018"

result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, arSA); //Getting error here
```

Comment: You aren’t converting to Hijiri date. The culture you provide to ParseExact is used to parse the input and doesn’t affect the output as DateTime itself is culture-less. You are getting the error because `dateString` is an US date string, but you are telling ParseExact it’s in Saudi-Arabian date format, which is obviously wrong. If you want the Hijiri date you need to apply it when you convert your parsed date to a string.

Comment: Also if you just want to convert a Gregorian date to a Hijiri data you don’t need all these Parse/ParseExact/ToStrings as like I said DateTime is culture-less. Just one `dt.ToString("d", arSA)` should suffice. The "d" means short date format.